# DEBUG Query Output when using Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I want to visualize the query that Neo4JClient generates for my code.

Is there any way to get the Cypher Query that has been translated.

I tried using the following construct, but it returns an error saying that a void return cannot be assigned to a intrinsic local variable.

```
var qry= client.Cypher
    .Merge("(dataspace:DataSpace { DataSpaceName: {dataspacename} })")
    .OnCreate()
    .Set("dataspace = {newDataSpace}")
    .WithParams(new {
        dataspacename = newDataSpace.DataSpaceName,
        dataspacedescription = newDataSpace.DataSpaceDescription,
        newDataSpace
        }
    )
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Errror returned : Compiler Error Message: CS0815: Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grab the query before you execute it:

```
var query = client.Cypher
    .Merge("(dataspace:DataSpace { DataSpaceName: {dataspacename} })")
    .OnCreate()
    .Set("dataspace = {newDataSpace}")
    .WithParams(new {
        dataspacename = newDataSpace.DataSpaceName,
        dataspacedescription = newDataSpace.DataSpaceDescription,
        newDataSpace
        }
    )
```

There are more specific notes in the documentation: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#debugging

Comment: I also have a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101026/how-to-delete-nodes-recursively-from-a-start-node   can you throw some light on it.